# Ingreso de un solo dato a la base de datos PHP

Tags: php, mysql, html5

Hola tengo el siguiente código, he usado este mismo pero para un `array` pero no para un solo dato, ¿qué estoy poniendo mal?

**Modelo**

```
<?php
    require_once 'conexion.php';
    class ModeloOBPYC{
    /*=============================================
    CREAR OBPYC
    =============================================*/
    static public function mdlInsertarOB($tabla, $dato){
        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO $tabla(observacion) VALUES (:observacion)");
        $stmt->bindParam(":observacion", $dato["observacion"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        if($stmt->execute()){
            return "ok";
        }else{
            return "error";
        }
        $stmt->close();
        $stmt = null;
    }
}
```

Como se ve solo estoy obteniendo un solo valor del POST del HTML que es obs y es el único pero no entiendo cual es el error.

Este al final me marca error en la vista, que estoy haciendo mal

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si solo tienes un valor que recibes por qué no solo pasas a la variable $observacion ?

Comment: me podrías ayudar con algo de código para visualizar mejor

Comment: Ya probaste lo que te comenté?

Comment: asi ?
`$stmt->bindParam($observacion, PDO::PARAM_STR);`

Comment: ya lo resolvi amigo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo resuelto eran tan simple que no me di cuenta:

```
<?php
require_once 'conexion.php';
class ModeloOBPYC{
/*=============================================
CREAR OBPYC
=============================================*/
static public function mdlInsertarOB($tabla, $dato){
    $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO $tabla(observacion) VALUES (:observacion)");
    $stmt->bindParam(":observacion", $dato, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    if($stmt->execute()){
        return "ok";
    }else{
        return "error";
    }
    $stmt->close();
    $stmt = null;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si no estoy mal ese error te esta saliendo por que tus últimas dos líneas nunca seran alcanzadas por los `return` debes ponerlas antes de los `return`

```
<?php
    require_once 'conexion.php';
    class ModeloOBPYC{
    /*=============================================
    CREAR OBPYC
    =============================================*/
    static public function mdlInsertarOB($tabla, $dato){
        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO $tabla(observacion) VALUES (:observacion)");
        $stmt->bindParam(":observacion", $dato["observacion"], PDO::PARAM_STR);            
        
        if($stmt->execute()){
            $stmt->close();
            $stmt = null;
            return "ok";
        }else{
            $stmt->close();
            $stmt = null;
            return "error";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: no amigo no funciono

Comment: Lo estabas menjando como arreglo y era un string